# Gremlin Queries: How to exclude ID while including label in valuemap?

Tags: database, search, graph, gremlin, tinkerpop

So I have a gremlin query like this:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Person').valueMap(true, 'name')
```

Now this creates a valuemap with the fields/columns 'Label', 'ID' and 'name', but how do I exclude 'ID' from this?

I only want 'Label' and 'name' to be included as the results.

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer using WithOptions probably works, but I got an error message when I tried it (I'm sending gremlin queries as a string using an API, so it might be an error on the server-side of the API).

However, I figured out another way to do this.

With labels:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Person').project('label', 'name').by(label).by(values('name').fold())
```

With IDs:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Person').project('id', 'name').by(id).by(values('name').fold())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WithOptions` to control this.

Here is an example using the air-routes data set

```
gremlin> g.V('3').valueMap('city').with(WithOptions.tokens,WithOptions.ids)
==>[id:3,city:[Austin]]

gremlin> g.V('3').valueMap('city').with(WithOptions.tokens,WithOptions.labels)
==>[label:airport,city:[Austin]]
```

Comment: Thank you! I got the error message "No such property: WithOptions for class", however I figured out another way to do this :)

Comment: You need to make sure if you are doing this from code that you include the relevant classes and enums. Which Gremlin client are you using? From Java, as an example it is located here `org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.WithOptions`

Comment: If you are sending the queries as strings it will potentially depend on the back end database you are connected to as to whether or not `WithOptions` is supported.